# SIP command not found

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I have installed asterisk on Ubuntu Natty,

When I go into asterisk CLI & type in sip reload or any SIP related commands, it says SIP command not found.

Anyone had a similar problem before?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check, if the SIP channel module is loaded:

The command `module show` should have this line in its response:

`chan_sip.so                    Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)`

If not, check if this module is installed (should be, by default) and
check the startup messages in the log files of asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled from source, you may be missing the OpenSSL development library.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl-dev  (or libssl-dev on Precise)
./configure
make
make install
```